# i am trying to put some number in the memory and print it, but my code is just stop without any problem message

Tags: c, pointers, memory

This is my first time quesiton, so my explanation could be bad.....

I want to allocate memory for arr1 and arr2 to store and output four numbers each. There is no problem with compiling, but if you run the code, the program automatically with put the third number in the memory arr1.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void ARR1_INPUT(int **arr1, int size)

{
    *arr1 = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
    if (arr1 != NULL)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            printf("put your number of %d index -> ", i + 1);
            scanf("%d", arr1[i]);
        }
    }
    else printf("Memory allocation fail");

}


void ARR2_INPUT(int **arr2, int size){

    *arr2 = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
    if (arr2 != NULL)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
           printf("put your number of %d index -> ", i + 1);
            scanf("%d", arr2[i]);
        }
    }
    else printf("Memory allocation fail"):
}

int main(void){
    int size;
    int *arr1;
    int *arr2;
    printf("how many number are you gonna put in each memory -> "); scanf("%d", &size);

    ARR1_INPUT(&arr1, size);
    ARR2_INPUT(&arr2, size);

    printf("%d, %d, %d, %d", arr1[0], arr1[1], arr1[2], arr1[3]);
    printf("%d, %d, %d, %d", arr2[0], arr2[1], arr2[2], arr2[3]);
    free(arr1);
    free(arr2)
}
```

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: What if the user inputs any value below `4` for `size`? No need to define to read two separate functions to do same work, define one & re-use it. Check `if (arr2 != NULL)` is wrong in that context.

Comment: Why do you need two identical functions? You can just pass any array to any to any of them, so drop one of and call the remaining one with both arrays! Correct type for specifying array or object sizes is `size_t` from `stddef.h`, by the way, and all uppercase function names are not recommendable, usually *macros* are defined in that format, so you risk confusion...

Answer (score 2):

There were some errors in the code. I'll just post the second function with comments. Mostly, it's because of wrong level of indirection.

```
void ARR2_INPUT(int **arr2, int size){
    *arr2 = malloc(sizeof(int) * size);     // cast is undesirable
    if (*arr2 != NULL)                      // was incorrect level of indirection
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
           printf("put your number of %d index -> ", i + 1);
           scanf("%d", &(*arr2)[i]);        // was incorrect level of indirection
        }
    }
    else printf("Memory allocation fail");  //: was syntax error
}
```

Also as commented, the code reports exactly 4 array elements: this should be done in loops controlled by `size`.

There are other improvements that can be made, such as checking the return value from the `scanf` calls, and better follow-through from  failed memory allocation.